# How to fix "undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_mutexattr_settype@@GLIBC_2.2.5'"

Tags: linker-errors

I am runnint Fedora 29 Linux and I'm trying to compile Scribus from source, using the instructions about 2/3 of the way down [this](https://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Building_SVN_versions_with_CMake#Version_1.5.x) page. All goes well until make gets to the link stage, at which point I get this error:

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpodofo.a(PdfFontConfigWrapper.cpp.o):
>   undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_mutexattr_settype@@GLIBC_2.2.5'

I have double-checked that I have fontconfig-devel and podofo-devel correctly installed.

The Scribus list has been unable to solve this one yet and suggest it is not a Scribus config issue, so I am at a dead end.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Kind regards, Doug

Comment: It looks like you have installed libpodofo either from source, or in a non-standard way. I suggest you try installing the dependencies using `dnf`, e.g. `sudo dnf install podofo-libs`. Or just install Scribus itself using dnf, rather than trying to compile it from source.

Comment: Thanks Robin - you were correct. I had compiled 1.9.5 from source at some stage and that was causing problems. It was one of many issues I had to clear up before I could get Scribus-1.5.5_svn to compile. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem was complex and I would not have arrived at it without all the help I have received.

- I had an ancient version of podofo which I had compiled at some time in the past. Removing that started to make a difference;
- I was given a dnf command to ensure everything necessary was installed, so I ran that and it found a few I had missed;
- I had an elderly, compiled version of Scribus 1.4.6 sitting in /usr/local, so I deleted that;
- I found the commands on [this](https://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Building_SVN_versions_with_CMake#Version_1.5.x) page lacked a tiny bit of vital information. The line:
  svn co svn://scribus.net/trunk/Scribus
  should read:
  svn co svn://scribus.net/trunk/Scribus scribus155
- And, to cap it all off, I had and old and a new version of GLIBC, which was confusing things.

With all these matters corrected, the cmake, make and make install went without a hitch. All I had to do was create a menu entry and assign the correct Scribus logo to it and now I can run Scribus the way I expect to run it.

Many thanks everyone for all your help. I love the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

On LinuxMint

Got the same error after building Scribus since year dot. Why?

Eventually from another machine, I noticed a recommendation;
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:

> libpodofo0.9.5

So I had autoremoved it, this led to `cmake` telling me that there was no `podofo` which led me to build it `/usr/local` and then that error.

Eventually needed to do an `apt install libpodofo-dev` as well as remove the `/usr/local` build.

All was well again!